# Cookies not accurate if people share the same IP address?

Tags: perl, cookies, session-cookies

When user **A** connects to my web site I set a cookie to this user’s browser to identify him and to track what he is doing to deliver content in accordance to his behaviour.

When user **B** *connects and comes from the same IP* address then user **B** gets user **A’s** cookies and vice versa. It would seem the cookies get mixed up because the web server is seeing one user instead of several as several users are coming from the same IP.

This problem only occurs with one set of users that use the same ISP. This ISP assigns the same IP address (and hostname) to multiple accounts/users. (Many people share one IP) If two people (or more) from this same ISP on the same IP shows up on my site then cookie operations seems to be shared amongst them which is causing problems.

What can be done to accurately track individual users when they are coming from the same IP (sharing an IP address) as cookies seem to not work properly when this happens? Perhaps the problem is coming from the ISP in question?

Will SSL solve this? Perhaps it’s the way I set the cookies?

I'm posting an example below in Perl on how I set cookies:

```
use CGI;
$q = CGI->new;

### the routine &get_random_number used below is a unique random number 
### generator that also uses $ENV{HTTP_USER_AGENT} for entropy
### &get_random_number returns a unique number (session id)
$session_id = &get_random_number; 

$thecookie1 = $q->cookie(-name=>'something', -value=> $session_id );
print $q->header(-cookie => $thecookie1);
```

This is the code that reads the cookie:

```
use CGI;
$q = CGI->new;
$thecookie = $q->cookie('something');
```

***The situation explained here in this post only happens with a specific ISP (All users using this ISP is coming from the same IP and has the same hostname) - The ISP shares a single IP with many users. This ISP provides mobile internet for cell phones.***

**Update 1:**

I believe it must have something to do with a caching proxy server implemented by the ISP in question as this only happens with the ISP in question.

I have done the following in the hopes of solving it: (The number of times the problem occurred decreased drastically) - The last change I made
was adding no-cache meta tags to the page setting the cookies which I hope completely solves it. Time will tell probably.

From the page setting cookies I do the following:

```
print $q->header(-type=>'text/html',
-Pragma=>'no-cache',
-Cache_Control=> 'no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0',
-expires=>'now -1d',
-cookie=> $cookie
); 

print qq[
<head>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" /> 

etc... etc...
];
```

**Update 3:**

Upgrading Apache seemed to solve it but the problem came back. I did solve it but **the only way I could get it solved was to move everything to https://**

Moving to https:// solved it period.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is really answerable. We don't really know enough about your environment to be able to say. How _do_ you set the cookies? It could be that. It could be their ISP doing dirty things with caching and proxying.

Comment: don't set cookies based on IP address - use session semantics in whatever server environment you use

Comment: "When user B connects and comes from the same IP address then user B gets user A’s cookies" — As Sobrique implied, this is not normal behaviour.

Comment: That is not expected behaviour, if it were the fundamental concept of cookie based session state simply would not work; which it does.  Something else is wrong.

Comment: I guess it's the way you set cookies. Cookies aren't shared by their own nature: when you set a cookie, it's a *personal* cookie. Su just assign an unique id in that cookie and you should be golden - as far as they use just one browser, of course. Otherwise, it's the old problem of fingerprinting the device (no definite solution in a sandboxed browser environment).

Comment: Within your system are you making the assumption that an IP uniquely identifies a user?

Comment: How sure are you that your session IDs are unique? Have you tried capturing those?

Comment: Show the code for `get_random_number`. If multiple people use the same browser (which seems likely since Safari alone has over 40% of the mobile market share), you won't be getting much entropy out of the user agent string. (HTTP headers are easily forged, so you shouldn't rely on them to create your session IDs *anyway*.) @Sobrique may be on to something.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that these users share a caching proxy. Be sure to disable caching of the response containing the `Set-Cookie` header. We do that by outputting the CGI header as follows:

```
print header(-type=>'text/html', -expires=>'now -1d', -cookie=>\@cookies);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm in agreement with you on this as this is the only thing that makes sense. Can you perhaps explain a bit more what -expires=>'now -1d' does? (I need the cookie to not expire immediately because I want to track future visits from the user)

Comment: That's when the *response* expires, not the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I realise you consiider this issue solved by the Apache update but I assure you that's not what "fixed" it. Upgrading Apache has just resulted in some changes to your configuration and if you restore your original configuration the problem will re-occur in the new version too. In other words this also certainly isn't an Apache bug you're seeing but a problem with how you configured it.

Basically it looks like you had a situation where Apache was setting its own cache headers in addition to or replacing the ones you set via Perl. You may have been doing this via `mod_headers` or through a mis-configuration of `mod_expires` or `mod-cache`

Answer (score -4):

Cookies don't have anything to do with IP addresses, they are created client side and linked to the browser.  For instance if a user logged in to your website using Chrome they would have a different set of cookies than if the logged in using IE on the same computer (and IP address).

I suggest your problem may be to do with what you are putting in the cookies, which is completely up to you and your code.

Have you tried using sessions instead?  In PHP, you just need to call session_start() and then set data in the $_SESSION variable.

If you post some example code of what you are doing, I might be able to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: "Have you tried using sessions instead?" — Sessions are associated with a browser by means of … a cookie.

Comment: Yes, sessions do use cookies, but they take away the need to explicitly set the cookie yourself (in PHP at least).

Comment: Cookies _can_ be created by client-side Javascript, _or_ they can be generated on the server and sent to the client via a `Set-Cookie` header.  In either case it is the browser's job to store the cookie and return it in the `Cookie` header of subsequent requests.